# Unable to clone git repo with two submodules

Tags: git, azure, github

I have a Barebones Git Repo with two submodules, viz., Client & Server. Trying to deploy to Azure. Get an error on Syncing saying "fatal: Needed a single revision. Unable to find current revision in submodule path ...". When I clone the Repo to my harddisk, the submodules are not cloned but `git submodule update --recursive --init` works.

Tried `git submodule update --recursive --init` and  `git submodule foreach git pull` in App Service Console. Still no show. I get a timeout error saying "command aborted due to no CPU activity or output for 60 seconds".

I was expecting the entire codebase to be cloned to Azure and deployed.

Comment: *timeout error saying "command aborted due to no CPU activity or output for 60 seconds".* The commands is trying to ask something interactively (password?) but there is no terminal so the command wait for an answer indefinitely.

Comment: I am running these commands from the Console under Development Tools in Azure App Service Blade. I can see a little spinner going round and round for about a minute before this error message shows up.  There is no prompt message during this time. Like when I try to delete the directory contents forcefully I do see a prompt asking me if I am sure. Although it does not wait for me to answer and returns to command prompt.